# Is it possible to pause a job in a PBS scheduler?

Tags: linux, bash, unix, state, pbs

I have jobs running in a supercomputer, when I've submitted a new one it has entered in waiting status (qw). This last job is priority in relation with the ones that are running which I don't want to kill. What I'd like to do is to pause them and let the important one to run. Is that possible?

Comment: In theory you could add a dependency on the lower priority jobs like qalter -Wdepend=afterok:<high_priority_job_id> <lower_priority_jobid> ... Not sure if ordinary users can alter dependencies on their jobs.

Comment: Is your cluster set up to allow job preemption and BLCR?